# use of undeclared type `ParquetWriter`

Tags: rust, rust-polars

This seems very simple, but I don't understand ...

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn write_df_to_parquet(df: &mut DataFrame) {
    let mut file = File::create("df.parquet").expect("could not create file");

    ParquetWriter::new(&mut file)
    .finish(df)
}
```

gives `` use of undeclared type `ParquetWriter` `` .

Isn't `ParquetWriter` imported in the `use polars::prelude::*;` line?

The example given here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/51e0e40457d5f2f224df0a4dcf389ced16fbac05/examples/read_csv/src/main.rs

Seems to be accessing `ParquetWriter` with just that import?

I'm sure I'm missing something silly.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the full error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE). Yes [`ParquetWriter` should be part of the prelude](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.ParquetWriter.html) unless you're using a very old version of polars (it was added in v0.12).

Answer (score 2):

I searched found the implementation of `ParquetWriter` in the [source](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/51e0e40457d5f2f224df0a4dcf389ced16fbac05/polars/polars-io/src/parquet/write.rs), and followed the `pub use` chain. It seams that in the prelude `polars-io` (the crate in which `ParquetWriter` is implemented) is listed as a feature.

I suspect the feature you need is not installed. Even the `polars-io` crate itself has a feature for the parquet structs. It too needs to be installed. To install them add these lines to your `Cargo.toml` file, in the workspace root.

**Note that you need to change the version of `polars-io` to match to the one of `polars`, otherwise there will be dependency mismatches.**

```rust
polars = { version = "0.24.2", features = ["polars-io"] }
polars-io = { version = "0.24.2", features = ["parquet"] }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had these dependencies in my `Cargo.toml`, but did not have the features called out.  Adding them resolved the issue.

I am struggling with understanding when to add what "features" to the `Cargo.toml` dependencies.  E.g. in the documentation for `ParquetWriter` here: https://docs.rs/polars-io/0.24.1/polars_io/parquet/struct.ParquetWriter.html it says "Available on crate feature `feature` only."  Using that did not work, but adding your suggested feature `parquet` did work.  I was able to drop the `polars-io` feature with no negative consequences.

Comment: I found the answer to the question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761045/how-to-tell-what-features-are-available-per-crate). To sum it up you just go to the [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/) page and go to the features tab. It should list every feature and their uses, but it depends on how good the docs for that particular crate are.

Comment: Thanks @toni1606!  This helps go from a crate to what features are defined.  But it doesn't help with when I find an element that I want to use, e.g. `ParquetWriter`, but it fails despite adding the dependency to `Cargo.toml`.  Here one can guess, but I'm trying to learn about rust.  Inspection of the `ParquetWriter` [code](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/51e0e40457d5f2f224df0a4dcf389ced16fbac05/polars/polars-io/src/parquet/write.rs) doesn't show any hints that a feature is required (e.g. `cfg`?  Do you know how can to tell from the code, what feature to include?

Comment: Yes you just go to the definition of the module, not it's implementation in this case it is not in the definition of the `writer` itself, but in it's parent module called `parquet`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/51e0e40457d5f2f224df0a4dcf389ced16fbac05/polars/polars-io/src/lib.rs). You just have to go up the hierarchy of modules until you find the `#[cfg(feature = "<feature_name>")]` on the module in which your type is located.

Comment: Maybe this makes it work: `cargo add polars --features parquet`

Answer (score 0):

Update for later versions

```ini
[dependencies.polars]
version = "0.28"
features = ["parquet"]
```