# Convert Postgres timestamp to Rust Chrono

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-chrono

How to covert a PostgreSQL `timestamp` (with time zone) to Rust Chrono `DateTime<Utc>`?

Example: `2020-04-12 22:10:57.0+02`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read a timestamp with timezone (timestamptz) value from PostgreSQL in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760741/how-can-i-read-a-timestamp-with-timezone-timestamptz-value-from-postgresql-in)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the custom parser from `str`:

```rust
let date_str = "2020-04-12 22:10:57.000+02";
// convert the string into DateTime<FixedOffset>
let datetime = DateTime::parse_from_str(&date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.f%#z").unwrap();
// convert the string into DateTime<Utc> or other timezone
let datetime_utc = datetime.with_timezone(&Utc);
```

[Extra info](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime/index.html):

- `%.f` => `.026490`: Similar to `.%f` but left-aligned. These all consume the leading dot.
- `%#z` => `+09`: *Parsing only:* Same as `%z` but allows minutes to be missing or present.

For more info, see [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179071/2037998).

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres type `TIMESTAMP` is only convertible to chrono's `NaiveDateTime`.

In order to convert to chrono's `DateTime<Utc>`, you must use the Postgres type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for your column.